# How to embed PDF.JS viewer in a page without iframe

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I'm surprised to see that there is relatively few documentation and tutorials on PDF.JS, especially since the code refactoring `PDFJS -> pdfjsLib`, considering this library is pretty widely used.

What I want to do is relatively simple, I just want to embed a PDF directly in a webpage, i.e. without `<iframe>`, `<object>` or `<embed>` tags. I also want to use the text layer because I want to access the text in JavaScript and add tooltips on some sentences.

I figured using the viewer might be a solution, but I don't want to include all the code in `viewer.html`, `viewer.css` and `viewer.js` inside my webpage because I'm sure it would break. If I can just display the PDF and select the text it would be enough, I don't necessarily need the complex user interface of the viewer.

Here is my code but the text layer is not displayed properly:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.worker.js';
});

function displayReport() {
  const file = document.getElementById('reportInput').files[0];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = async function() {
    const data = this.result;
    const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: data}).promise;
    const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
    const viewport = page.getViewport({scale: 0.5});

    const canvas = document.getElementById('reportCanvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    const renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    await page.render(renderContext).promise;
    const textContent = await page.getTextContent();

    const { top, left, width, height } = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const textLayer = document.getElementById('reportTextLayer');
    textLayer.style.top = top;
    textLayer.style.left = left;
    textLayer.style.width = width;
    textLayer.style.height = height;

    await pdfjsLib.renderTextLayer({
      textContent: textContent,
      container: textLayer,
      viewport: viewport,
      textDivs: []
    });

    console.log("Page rendered!");
  };
  fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
}
```

```css
#reportTextLayer {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0.2;
  line-height: 1.0;
}

#reportTextLayer > div {
  color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  cursor: text;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.js"></script>

<p>Select a PDF file:</p>
<input id="reportInput" type="file" accept="application/pdf" onchange="displayReport()"/>

<div id="reportWrapper">
    <canvas id="reportCanvas"></canvas>
    <div id="reportTextLayer"></div>
</div>
```

How can I fix that?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
[script type="text/javascript" src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"][/script]
[script type="text/javascript" src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js"][/script]
[style type="text/css"]
#signature {
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
[/style]


    <canvas id='the-canvas'></canvas>
    <div id='signature'></div>

    [script]

    var url = "Agreement.pdf";
    var loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(url);
    loadingTask.promise.then(function(pdf) {
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: scale, });

    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = 640;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    var renderContext = {
    canvasContext: context,
    viewport: viewport
    };
    page.render(renderContext);

    });    
    });

   document.getElementById('signature').innerHTML = 'Signed By Yogi on 1/26/2021'

   [/script]
```

Comment: This works but is very bare bones, ie: no toolbar, scrollbar, zoom ,etc. Have you improved on it since?